# Не закрывается процеесс excel при использовании interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

```
 Excel.Application excel = null;
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
        Excel.Sheets worksheets = null;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;

        excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filePath))
        {
            excel.DisplayAlerts = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Вы не выбрали файл", "Внимание!",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
            return list;
        }
        workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
        workbook = workbooks.Open(_filePath);
        worksheets = workbook.Worksheets;
        worksheet = worksheets.Item[1];

        int rows = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int cols = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
```

\\

тут считываются ячейки примерно вот так :

```
string? fio = (string)(worksheet.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;

int age = (int)(worksheet.Cells[i, 3] as Excel.Range).Value2;
```

\\

```
        excel.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        GC.Collect();

        return Person.personlist;
```

я предполагаю, что тут мешается подсчёт использованных ячеек в переменные rows и cols. Если так и есть, то подскажите, пожалуйста, как их можно по другому реализовать?
Если не в них, то всё же в чём и как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте поищите другие библиотеки для парсинга excel, можно руцями распарсить через zip + xmlreader (только словарь отдельно вычитать). interop  - самое кривое что есть. Openoffice вроде неплохо читает.

Comment: По идее Quit в последнюю очередь, перед самим  `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);` лучше поставить. interop себя странно ведет, я сталкивался с тем, что он все документы при Quit закрывает., и паралельно открытые в excel тоже. Так же Quit может помешать любой диалог excel-ля. Ну.... в крайнем случае можно через Diagnostics найти процесс Excel.exe и грохнуть его через kill.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Да, это помогло. Поменял место Quit(), а ещё нашёл объявление excel'евских переменных в форме запуска окна :) после удаления всё чисто, аки простыни из стирки. Спасибо!

Comment: Рекомендую переменные объявлять при первом использовании, а не заранее. Так код лучше читаться будет.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло поставить функцию Quit() прямо перед отпусканием самого приложения.
То есть так:

```
 Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
                excel.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```

И ещё нашёл лишний запуск экселя в форме окна, то есть при запуске приложения объявлялись переменные и соответсвенно запускался эксель

Comment: Воркбук ещё надо закрыть перед высвобождением объекта. Плюс на случай исключений стоит использовать try-finally